# Adding table lock manually to specified table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, insert, table-lock

I want to INSERT into one tables but prevent INSERTING to another one. It is possible to LOCK for example table **a** for INSERTING, INSERT to table **b** and then UNLOCK table **a**?

TABLOCK can lock only the table I am INSERTING in.

Thanks

Martin Pilch

Comment: Why do you need to lock the other table? That might affect the best solution for your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server does not allow locking objects like you would do semaphors. Also, locking a table will not make it read-only; it will make it locked out for everybody.

You can place a lock by using a table hint such as `SELECT * FROM MyTable WITH (LOCKNAME)` but that is not a good programming practice.

Comment: Thanks, maybe if it will be necessary to do it, I will create table with flag, setting this flag when inserting and checking it when inserting to another table.